# No new privileges flag is set error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sudo

I created a new user called jump using `sudo adduser jump` and then gave it root permissions using: `sudo usermod -aG sudo jump`. I then switched to my user using: `su - jump`, and ran: `sudo curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ -o get-docker.sh`, but get the error:

> sudo: The "no new privileges" flag is set, which prevents sudo from
> running as root. sudo: If sudo is running in a container, you may need
> to adjust the container configuration to disable the flag.

Could you please help me out?